# HashMap for Student Object does not print objects of Student

Tags: object, hashmap

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentMap extends Student{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student[] studentClass = new Student[2];
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=1;i<=studentClass.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name for "+i+"Student");
            String studentName = s1.next();
            System.out.println("Enter email for "+i+"Student");
            String email = s1.next();
            System.out.println("Enter phone number for "+i+"Student");
            Integer num = s1.nextInt();
            studentClass[i] = new Student();
            studentClass[i].setName(studentName);
            studentClass[i].setEmail(email);
            studentClass[i].setPhoneNumber(num);
        }
        s1.close();
        for(Student stu : studentClass)
        {
            System.out.println(stu.name);
            System.out.println(stu.email);
            System.out.println(stu.phoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

While executing this code it gives an error of OutOfBoundIndex ..
I have created Student class to which has all get set method for name, email and phoneNumber.

Comment: Array can hold only 2 elements , while in 1st for loop you are doing something like this `studentClass[2]` , which is causing this exception. Initialize `i=0` instead of `i=1` and put the termination condition for loop as `i<stdudentClass.length`. i.e remove `=`

Comment: Since I'm guessing this is homework, I'll try to nudge you in the right direction while having you think through the answer. Two questions for you: a) since studentClass is an array of length == 2, what's the maximum index you can legally access in it? (Hint: it's less than 2) And b) with your code right now, what's the maximum value that `i` will ever reach? Once you can answer those, the problem in the code will become clear.